# How to store multiple values in a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a function that saves the links to youtube movies,

```
angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){

  $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
  $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
  var youtubeLink = $scope.youtubeTrailer.toString();
  createTrailer.create({
    link:     youtubeLink,
    movie_id: $scope.movieListID.id
  }).then(init);

})
```

The trailer rails controller,

```
def create
  respond_with Trailer.create(trailer_params)
end

private
def trailer_params
  params.require(:trailer).permit(
    :link,
    :movie_id
  )
end
```

And the trailer rails model,

```
belongs_to :movie
```

The `forEach` creates a new record for every trailer.

```
{"id":1,"movie_id":"312221","link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:15:35.681Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:15:35.681Z"},
{"id":2,"movie_id":"281957","link":"EIELwayIIT4","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:46:25.248Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:46:25.248Z"},
{"id":3,"movie_id":"291270","link":"WQkHA3fHk_0","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:50:15.563Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:50:15.563Z"},
{"id":4,"movie_id":"291270","link":"LUloSK4x3qc","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:50:15.651Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:50:15.651Z"},
{"id":5,"movie_id":"209112","link":"nIGtF3J5kn8","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z"},
{"id":6,"movie_id":"209112","link":"yViIi3gie2c","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z"},
{"id":7,"movie_id":"209112","link":"Onh7NbZ7F8o","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z"},
{"id":8,"movie_id":"312221","link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z"},
```

As you might see it creates 3 records for 3 trailers with the same `movie_id` > `209112`.

Would it be possible to save the data so it would group those trailers with the same movie_id together? So it would look like this,

```
{"id":312221,
  "links"{
    {"link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:15:35.681Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:15:35.681Z"},
  }
}

{"id":281957, 
  "links"{
    {"link":"EIELwayIIT4","created_at":"2016-01-05T14:46:25.248Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T14:46:25.248Z"},
  }
}

{"id":291270",
  "links"{
    {"link":"WQkHA3fHk_0","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z"},
    {"link":"yViIi3gie2c","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z"},
    {"link":"LUloSK4x3qc","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z"},
  }
}

{"id":209112",
  "links"{
    {"link":"Onh7NbZ7F8o","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.550Z"},
    {"link":"yViIi3gie2c","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.469Z"},
    {"link":"nIGtF3J5kn8","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:21:11.372Z"},
  }
}

{"id":312221,
  "links"{
    {"link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probably saving the records correctly in the db, you may just need to create a nested json response in rails.  So the trailers are included in the movie json.

You can do this a few different ways, but try this...

In your controller change the respond_with to

```
def create
  @trailers = Trailer.create(trailer_params)
  respond_with Movie.where(:id => @trailers.map(:movie_id))
end
```

And in them movie model, include the trailers collection

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options={})
    {
      :id          => id,
      :trailers    => trailers
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question, or I'm misunderstanding the answer but I don't see how to resolves my issue. My issue is that the forEach function creates a new record for each trailer link. I would like to create one containing object that has all the relevant trailer links.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood, I thought link was an object.  What you really want is a list of movies with the trailers embedded.  Do you want all the movies for the trailers you just uploaded?

Comment: Instead of saving each link value and movie_id value into a single record I would like to create one record that has all the link values for that movie. So the result would be something like `{"id":1, "movie_id":312221,
  "links"{
    {"link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z","updated_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z"}
  }
}`

Comment: In a relational db, the collection will be saved in a separate table.  What db are you using for the rails end?  And, if you look at the response (response.results), to change this, you need to modify the json output from the rails controller.

Comment: I'm using the SQLite database. The problem is that it's not a collection. Every link gets saved as a seperate record. I want to save each link into a single record.

Comment: OK - Updated my answer with something you can try.  The json you specified is really a list of movies with trailers embedded.  This would match the db `movies: [ {"id":312221, "trailers"{ {"link":"LsjX5dqHLuw","created_at":"2016-01-05T15:26:19.701Z","updated_at":"2016‌​-01-05T15:26:19.701Z"} } }]`.  It seems like what you really want back is a list of movies with the trailers (and their links) included

Comment: Alright, I've set up a has_many relation between movies and trailers, but there are two things going wrong. When I create a new movie record I get an error `NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for #<Trailer'` although the links are being added in the trailer model. And if I do `def as_json(options={})` then my movies.json only shows the record id and the trailers (which is empty), so no release dates, poster_paths etc.

Comment: OK - So sometimes the create does many trailers, sometimes only one?  You'll need to do account for that.  It's not RESTful to create one or many trailers and then return one or many movies, so this is already breaking conventions. Are all the trailers part of one movie or could they refer to many movies?  And for the movies json, make sure the movie has some trailers.  Check this in the db, or in `rails console`